# Geometry Nodes: Normals incorrect on extruded curve. How to fix/workaround?

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes, extrude

I have this railing (mounted on some posts, with a floor, and a tree trunk not relevant) [image: The railing]

, generated with these nodes: [image: nodes that handle the railing]
As you can see, the outer half of the railing is getting its normals flipped the wrong way. How should I avoid this flipping?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your specific solution:

[image]

---

you can flip faces like this:

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I will accept the answer in 6 minutes LW.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

How about this: first scale the radius to the inner ring, and extrude from that value to the outer ring.
[image]

Comment: I had considered that, but I would rather avoid it because of the extra maths amongst the nodes.

Comment: extra math, but less vertices ;-)

Comment: (Arc Radius + Rail Width / 2) / Arc Radius = Scale of the inner Ring, and then extrude from there.

Comment: Maybe I should do that, though. Would still have to flip the normals of the original curve so it looks right, but maybe this might help later on. I guess it depends on which requires more computing power: the extra nodes, or the extra vertices.

Comment: As you can see, you not only have a clean mesh here, but also one less extrude mesh node. In sum, this is less computational overhead.